# Moving Rails yield into a helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rendering my title tags like this (I am using the meta-tags gem):

*about.html*

```
= content_for :page_title, 'About page'
```

*application.html*

```
%title
  = yield(:page_title)
```

However I would like to move the yield into a helper file, so it will work something like this:

*about.html*

```
= title_tag_generator("About page")
```

*title_helper.rb*

```
def title_tag_generator(page_title)
  content_tag :title do
    yield(page_title)
  end
end
```

I keep getting the no block given (yield) though. Any advice?

Comment: `content_for` is already a helper designed to do what you want, I do not even see any change you are making using your `title_tag_generator` helper.

You are complicating stuff, where you do not need more complication. Just leave your code as it is.

Comment: I have my reasons. My actual code is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [The guide on capture helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

> content_for, however, can also be used in helper modules.

```
module YourViewHelper
    def title_tag_generator
        # Your complex code that I believe generates lot of HTML
        # And which can use content_for(:title) here
    end
end
```

Then you can call `title_tag_generator` in your views.

Comment: He doesn't need to _call_ `content_for`. It's been called elsewhere. Now he needs to yield to it.

Comment: If you have a look at the link, you'll see it's possible to use `content_for(:title)` just like you would use `yield(:title)`

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling your `title_tag_generator` in your view you aren't giving a block. When your helper method reaches the `yield` call it can't do anything and gives you a good error message. There really is no block given for the yield statement.

You can code round this though and check if there is a block to yield to with [`block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F):

```
def title_tag_generator(page_title)
  content_tag :title do
    if block_given?
      yield(page_title)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you will yield to a block if there is one or carry on happily if there is no block.

To call your helper method with a block you can then, optionally, do:

```
title_tag_generator('My Page') do |page_title|
  "My title is: " + page_title
end
```

or in HAML:

```
- title_tag_generator('My page') do |page_title|
  %strong= page_title
```

Comment: yeah, well, what should he do to provide a correct block? He wants to yield to a `content_for` here.

Comment: yeah, well, I've added an example. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I didn't test, but I have a gut feeling that this block won't do him any good. I don't see how that `content_for` is going to be invoked here.

Comment: It's just a `content_tag` so it's just going to return a `<title>` tag with the block content. I agree in this example it's not achieving a great deal but the comment on the question suggests that this is a simplified example. I'm getting downvotes so maybe I'm wide of the mark. I'll delete the answer if so.